# expose your own API to YQL

Tags: api, yql

I was wondering if someone knows a way to expose an already public API (e.g. LinkedIn's) through YQL.

Any ideas / insight of someone who has already done this would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup :) If you click "Community Tables" on the right of the [YQL Console](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/) you can see there are already over 600 tables made by other people for existing APIs.

Check out http://datatables.org/ for more information on how to build them (you basically make an XML file describing the structure of the API and then commit it to github).